# Extracting some values from raster as a matrix, doing a transformation and putting the transformed values to their original place

Tags: r, matrix, raster, r-raster

Let's say I have a raster image `x`:

```
library(raster)
x = raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals = c(rep(NA, 10), rnorm(80), rep(NA, 10)))
```

Now I convert the rows and columns that are not `NA`s into a `matrix`

```
x_mat = raster::as.matrix(x)
x_mat_complete = x_mat[complete.cases(x_mat),]
```

Here I do some modification to the matrix `x_mat_complete`:

```
x_mat_complete_modified = x_mat_complete + 1
```

Now, what I want is to put `x_mat_complete_modified` back to its place in the original raster image `x` in such a way that the `NA` pixels remain the same. I can't figure out how to do this.

In other words, I want to replace `x_mat_complete` with `x_mat_complete_modified` in the raster image `x` keeping all the `NA`s unmodified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do seems a bit iffy --- there are likely better ways that avoid creating a matrix, but here is a solution.

Example data with a minor change to better illustrate what complete cases does (remove all rows that have at least one `NA`)

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1)
x = raster(ncols=10, nrows=10, vals = c(rep(NA, 8), rnorm(84), rep(NA, 8)))   
x_mat = raster::as.matrix(x)
```

Solution

```
i = complete.cases(x_mat)
cc = x_mat[i,]
x[which(i),] = cc + 10
```

With your example data you could just do

```
set.seed(1)
x = raster(ncols=10, nrows=10, vals = c(rep(NA, 10), rnorm(80), rep(NA, 10)))   
y <- x + 10
```

See `trim` to remove outer rows and columns with NA values.

Comment: The model I am using requires the data to be a `matrix`. Therefore I somehow needed to figure this out. :)